# Iterating through colourspaces in openCV for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to make a simple program that shows me what the first frame of a video looks like when it's converted into the different colourspaces available in openCV.

I am trying to use an iterator like this:

```
for item in flags:
    arg = 'cv2.' + str(item)
    newCs = cv2.cvtColor(frame, arg)

    cv2.imshow('newCs', newCs)
    # if I press no, destroy
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('n'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # if I press yes, save and destroy
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('y'):
       filename = str(item) + '.jpg'
       cv2.imwrite(filename, newCs)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

where 'flags' is an array containing all the flags like 'COLOR_BGR2HSV' and arg successfully returns a string that looks like the flag you would enter manually into the function eg. 'cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV'

This program returns an error, saying that it was expecting an int in place of 'arg'

Is this because what I'm trying to do is impossible, or is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "what it looks like"? Color spaces  are more like how to encode color. Do you mean "how different color spaces look like when interpreted as BGR during rendering"??

Comment: Tbh I'm brand new to openCV and all this image processing stuff, but I found if I converted an image to a different colourspace (ie. HSV), when I used the imshow() method on it, it looks different. Is that merely due to the computer display rendering it expecting a BGR image?

Comment: yes that's right, imshow assumes BGR and renders as if it was BGR. OpenCV functions don't even know in which color space an image is represented.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for pointing that out, it simplifies a few things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error hints, that second param of `cv2.cvtColor()`, must be `int` code which tells the method which conversion formula needs to be invoked. And you are trying to pass a `str` value where, `int` is required.

Why would you store `COLOR_BGR2HSV` as `str` in a list and later concatenate it with `"cv2."` to make the situation more complex. You may simply create a list as `color_configs = [cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV, ...]` and later iterate it to get the job done.

However, if you have no way to changing that list, then there is a hacky way to do the same, I won't recommend you to follow that in first place. But you may use `eval`, with taking proper precautions and sanitizing the string input, before calling `eval` as:

```
for item in flags:
    mode = 'cv2.' + str(item)
    newCs = cv2.cvtColor(frame, eval(mode))
```

Comment: That's solved it, thanks, just an oversight/overcomplication on my part